# Why is this question non-constructive?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

Recently [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143170/actor-library-framework-for-c) has been closed.

Summary of the question: "I want to use the actor model in C++ (more precisely, remote actors), can someone indicate a framework supporting this concept?"

I do not understand in what sense this question does not "involve facts, references, or specific expertise" or why it "will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Whether such a framework exists or not is a **fact** which I would like to know
before we start to implement some ad-hoc solution in our team.

**EDIT**

Thanks to the moderator for the discussion. The question has been edited.
One of the main problems that have been identified in the original question is that the actor model, while quite well-understood, is not main stream, and
some background information was needed to make the focus of the question
clearer.

Answer (score 6):

The summary of the question is inaccurate, your question ends with:

> On wikipedia I have found some links to actor libraries for C++ and I have started to look at Theron. Before I dive too deep into the details and build an extended example with Theron, I wanted to ask if anybody has experience with any of these libraries and which one they would recommend.

There are two other libraries in the Wikipedia article, what's stopping you from trying them out? How can we possibly recommend any of the three, or anything else if we don't have no idea what your building? The only information you give us for your project is:

> Being able to use remote actors (actors living in different processes, possibly on different machines and communicating via TCP/IP) has higher priority for us because we have an application consisting of several processes deployed on different machines. Being able to use several actors living in the same process (possibly different threads) is also interesting, but has lower priority for the moment.

Any recommendation based on these parameters will be heavily opinion based, simply because there aren't enough parameters, there isn't an actual problem to be solved. It's really unanswerable, in the Stack Exchange sense, as there isn't a sane way for the best answer to make it to the top. And when I say best, I don't mean popular or favourite, but the answer or answers that actually solve the problem.

For further detail, please read:

- [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/),
- [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: @Giorgio Revise the question to tell us why the solutions you've already found (the three on Wikipedia) don't work for you, and then give us a little bit more detail for your project. You did mention remote actors, but that's not a sufficient description of your project.

Comment: We want to use Scala-like remote actors (as stated at the beginning of the question). Trying out all the libraries in wikipedia and maybe other libraries I can find if I search more will probably answer my question, but then I do not need to ask it here. If someone has already used Scala actors and a similar library for C++ they can post the answer immediately. I have tried to keep the question as short as possible, but if adding more details regarding what aspects of Scala actors we need can make the question better I can try it.

Comment: @Giorgio Well we aren't going to do your homework for you, Programmers is not a place where you should be asking for stuff that you are perfectly capable of doing yourself, but when you've hit a wall. I'm not expecting you to evaluate all possible solutions before asking, but you should at least start evaluating the one you find more appealing before you ask here. Adding more details for your project will definitely help, and hopefully will attract re-open votes, I'd like to see this one re-opened, but I personally won't cast my re-open vote if I doesn't get some from regular users.

Comment: @Giorgio And before you mention it, I know there are far worse recommendations questions around... We'll get them, eventually.

Comment: The question was not meant to ask other members to do my homework for me. I have been analyzing our problem for two months now. I have identified the actor model, tried it out in Scala, looked for C++ libraries, read the Theron docs. The wall is that I am not an expert in actors and maybe all the information I need and that I can collect myself during the next month can be provided by another more experienced user with a 10-line answer. I have added more details and background to the question. I hope it got better now.

Comment: @Giorgio Good update, thanks. And I meant the homework part light heartedly, I forgot to put a smiley in there. I'm re-opening the question, it still feels a bit not constructive to me, but it's certainly not bad enough to require moderator intervention (anymore). Can't promise it won't be closed by the community though.

Comment: I do not want to sound pedantic, but it is important to me to understand this to reduce the risk of future questions being closed. "How can we possibly recommend any of the three, or anything else if we don't have no idea what your building?": The Scala model is a well-defined model. The question was if a C++ library supports this model. IMO, without knowing what I want to build, it is possible to say which libraries cover this model and to what extent. I had left out details of our project on purpose so that an answer could be focused on this issue.

Comment: If it still feels non-costructive, I would rather edit it again before it is re-opened. It is a quite important project we are working at and I would not like it to be closed again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3030/discussion-between-giorgio-and-yannis-rizos)

Comment: @Giorgio Your update makes what you're looking for a lot more specific (but not too specific), and it will help us vet answers. We now have a concrete set of parameters to compare answers to, and decide which is the more helpful (you get to decide that by accepting and the community by upvoting). You've made it a lot more easier to spot spammers (intentional or not), and (to put it kindly) clueless answerers. Whether it feels not constructive to me or not is not something you should worry about, if you haven't yet, you'll soon notice that I have no issue closing questions when I'm certain.